# i am setting a Menu Bar with drop-down but the Problem is you can see In below code

Tags: html, css

i am setting a Menu Bar with drop-down but the Problem is you can see In below code

I have tried By Changing Margin and Padding But None of the thing worked

```css
  

  .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
        margin: -10px -126px;
    }

    .topnav #myLinks {
        display: visible;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 10px 20px;
    }

    .topnav a {
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
        display: block;
    }

    .topnav a.icon {
        background: black;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        margin: 5px 166px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        float: right;
        margin: 0px 81px;
    }

    }

    div#myLinks {
        margin: 0px 20px 0px 107px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="topnav">
          <a href="#home" class="active">
         <img src="Images/logo-black.png" alt="AudiLogo" />
          
          </a>
          <div id="myLinks">
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars">Menu</i>
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
```

I expect a dropdown but it is taking within the same Menu Line 
but the actual output i want is a drop down below the Menu when I click on it.

enter code here

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are u using JavaScript? Its just HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Raghu The code I've given is working fine as u can check by using the run Snippets above...

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code to show the sub navigation as you wanted to show. It still needs some styling and I assumed you wanted to use javascript as you did in your original code.

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
```

```css
.topnav {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 margin: -10px -126px;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
 display: visible;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 10px 20px;
}

.topnav a {
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
 background: black;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 margin: 5px 166px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
}

.active {
 background-color: #4caf50;
 color: white;
 float: right;
 margin: 0px 81px;
}

div#myLinks {
 margin: 0px 20px 0px 107px;
}
div#myLinks > a:first-child {
 margin-top: 52px;
}
div#myLinks > a {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
          <a href="#home" class="active">
         <img src="Images/logo-black.png" alt="AudiLogo" />
          
          </a>
          <div id="myLinks">
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars">Menu</i>
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still there is a problem drop down should appear after i click the Menu but

Comment: It should. Did you enclose your javascript with `<script></script>` tags and put it at the end of `<body>` html ?

Answer (score -2):

**pls try this code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .topnav {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color:white;
          position: relative;
          /*margin: -10px -126px;*/
        }

        .topnav #myLinks {
          display: none;
          background-color:white;
          margin:48px 0px;

        }
        .topnav #myLinks a {
            color: #000;
        }

        .topnav a {
          color: white;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
          display: block;
        }

        .topnav a.icon {
          background: black;
          display: block;
          position: absolute;

          top: 0;
         /*margin: 5px 166px;*/

        }

        .topnav a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;

        }

        .active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          float:right;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        }
        div#myLinks {
            margin: 0px 20px 0px 107px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            var menu = document.getElementById("myLinks");
            if(menu.style.display == "block"){
                menu.style.display = "none";
            }
            else{
                menu.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>    

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header>
            <!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
            <div class="topnav">
              <a href="#home" class="active">
                <img src="Images/logo-black.png" alt="AudiLogo">
              </a>
              <div id="myLinks">
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
              </div>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars">Menu</i>
              </a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```